# Why does the Null Hypothesis have to be "equals to" and not "greater than or equal to"?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

In an online lecture I saw an example of hypothesis testing:

> The mean (of something) is at least 12
>
> Claim: $\mu \geq 12 \implies H_0: \mu = 12$
>
> Opposite: $\mu \lt 12 \implies H_A: \mu < 12$

And the lecturer insisted that we must put the $=$ and not $\geq$ in the $H_0$. But why?

Furthermore, if we end up rejecting $H_0$, sure it could mean that $\mu < 12$, but doesn't that also mean the it's possible that $\mu > 12$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for using $H_0: \mu = 12$ is that, among the set of values that correspond to $\mu \geq 12$, $\mu = 12$ is the most conservative (also called least favorable) configuration.

Let us be more precise what conservative means here. Say we set certain value of the observed statistic $\hat{\mu}$ at which we are willing to consider the null hypothesis as false (also called critical value $c$). $c$ should naturally be smaller than 12 to provide evidence against the null. Since $\hat{\mu}$ is just one of many possible realizations of the statistic, there is always some possibility of observing a value of $\hat{\mu}$ even if $\mu \geq 12$. Luckily, if we know the distribution of the test statistic, wecan compute the probability of observing a value of $\hat{\mu}$ that is smaller than or equal to $c$. This probability is called the probability of Type 1 error.

You can compute the probability of Type 1 error for all configurations that correspond to the hypothesis $\mu \geq 12$. In the figure I plot the distributions of the test statistics under two different such configurations $C_1: \mu = 12$ and $C_2: \mu = 13$. I also plot the probabilities of Type 1 error under the critical value $10.36$ for the two hypotheses (the shaded area under the respective curve) . It is easy to see that the probability of Type 1 error is always bigger for the configuration $C_1: \mu = 12$ than for any other $C_2$ that would also correspond to the hypothesis $\mu \geq 12$. I assumed normality here, but this result holds for any distribution that the test statistic can take.

To sum up, the common practice (which also makes a lot of sense!) is to choose, within the set of configurations of the test that correspond to the null hypothesis, the one that gives you the highest probability of Type 1 error.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand the sentences with "Say we set certain value" and "of observing a value of $\hat{\mu}$"

Comment: Fill in "Say we set a critical value c." and "Since $\hat{\mu}$ is a random variable..."

Comment: @MatthiasSchmidtblaicher What does " I assumed normality here, but this result holds for any distribution that the test statistic can take." mean? I thought that z and t test statistics only work with normal distributions like mean and proportion? Is there other uses of test statistics outside of normal distribution data?

Comment: @bluejimmy, The point was that shifting the red distribution to the right in the graph can only reduce the shaded area (which corresponds to the probability of rejecting under $H_0$ at the fixed critical value of slightly more than $10$). This does not depend on the distribution being normal. (And yes, you can use test statistics outside of the normal distribution. The normal distribution is so widespread for test statistics because it is often hard to get the exact distribution of a test statistic, in which case we can use a normal approximation).